# Matlab: Cell column with mixed char/double entries - how to make all numerical?

Tags: matlab, types

I'm importing large datasets into Matlab from different Excel files. I use `[~,~,raw] = xlsread('myfile.xlsx')` to obtain a raw input into a single Matlab cell.

One column consists of interest rates, and the entries are imported as either CHAR (if they're decimal numbers) or DOUBLE (if they're rounded to integers).

Now, I want to slice out that column and get a numerical vector, which Matlab doesn't like. If i use str2num, all the CHAR entries are converted into DOUBLE, but the DOUBLES becomes NaN. Is there a function/solution to take into account that some entries are already DOUBLE?

Comment: Try use `isnumeric`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnumeric.html, are you using `cellfun` or a loop to apply `str2num` at the moment?

Comment: Can you give a small example of the raw data you have? Especially, the column you want to convert?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably work this into your existing code rather than create a whole new function but this should work for you. The functions not vectorized though but since it a cell vector I don't think that's an issue

```
function number = str2numThatHandelsNumericInputs(obj)

    if isnumeric(obj)
        number = obj;
    else
        number = str2num(obj);
    end

end
```

Or as Eitan points out a better function:

```
function num = str2numThatHandelsNumericInputs(num)        
    if ischar(num)
        num = str2num(num); 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I didn't quite understand your question, because I understood you have something like this:

```
raw = {...
    '1.2345'   , NaN
    3          , inf
    4          , @cos
    '567.1232' , { struct }
};
```

In which case you could just use `str2double`:

```
>> inds = cellfun('isclass', raw(:,1), 'char');     % indices to non-numeric data
>> raw(inds,1) = num2cell(str2double(raw(inds,1))); % convert in-place
>> [raw{:,1}].'                                     % extract numeric array

ans =

    1.2345
    3.0000
    4.0000
  567.1232
```

But is this what you mean?